# Why is the Welch bound for max cross-correlation not 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, signal-processing

I am trying to self-educate about m-sequences, which led me to the topic of the Welch lower bounds on the maximum cross-correlation of sets of vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$. The Wikipedia page "Welch bounds", following the 1974 paper by LR Welch, starts off as follows:

"If $\{x_1,\ldots,x_m\}$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$, define $c_\max = \max_{i\neq j} |\langle x_i, x_j \rangle|$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the usual inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$".  There is NO stipulation that the $m$ chosen vectors are equiangular or have any other special relationship. It is tacitly assumed that all possible pairs in the arbitrarily chosen set of m vectors should be compared by evaluating their inner products.  A formula is then derived for $c_\max$ as a function of $m$, $n$, and a dimensional parameter $k$.

I feel that something has been left out of the initial statement. Although the statement above forbids correlating any vector with itself ($c_{ii} = 1$), no other restriction is placed on our choice of vectors. Therefore we can always choose 2 unit vectors that almost coincide (separated by angle $\theta$), and as $\theta \rightarrow 0, |\langle x_i, x_j \rangle| \rightarrow 1$.  Since $c_\max$ is defined as the maximum value over the chosen set of $m$ vectors, and we appear to be allowed free choice in selecting any $m$ vectors from the infinity of unit vectors on $\mathbb{C}^n$, then we can always chose m vectors so that they  include a pair of almost coincident vectors with $c_{i,j} = 1 - \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is as small as we please.  Therefore $c_\max$ must always be $1$, and this does not depend on $m$, $n$, or $k$.

Obviously, this interpretation contradicts the whole point of the bounds derivation. So what have they omitted in their statement of the problem, or what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

The Welch bound is a bound from below.  Hence, the interesting part is not how large you can make $c_{\mathrm{max}}$ but how small you  can make it.

Geoetrically: The question "How "orthogonal" can you expect many vectors to be? " is the same as asking how small the Welch bound is.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - I have it figured out now.

Comment: What you say is what I suspected:  what they really mean is min(max(...)), not just max().  I'm not a mathematician, obviously,  but that seems so sloppy  ...   I don't have any trouble following the geometrical interpretation once we have that clear.  Thanks

Comment: Actually, I don't find the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch_bounds sloppy. It defines the constant $c_{\text{max}}$ and then says that the Welch Bound is a lower bound for this. That's true and not sloppy at all. That $c_{\text{max}}$ is also upper bounded by 1 and that this bound can be reached is left out, but well, this is straightforward to see (while the Welch bound is not that obvious).

Comment: You're right, of course. After some thought, I realised it's a cultural divide between scientific disciplines. In my area we make a lot of decisions on numeric data, but the arguments are verbal and any math expressions are used more like summaries. The logic of the verbal argument takes precedence over the symbolic expressions:  a method of working alien to mathematicians. The existence of a lower bound would be spelled out, not just implied by a relational sign.  I am not innumerate, but it comes as a nasty surprise to find I am insymbolic  :)